# How to compare two string values using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a table and one row contains an input field. And other row contains td values. I need to compare the value inside the input box with the td values inside table. But the oldDivision value and NewDivision values are alerted same. But not entering to the if condition. How to solve this?

```
$("#tblGroupItemDetails tbody tr").each(function(i, tr) {
  if (!$(tr).hasClass("tdItemMaster")) {

    var oldDivision = $(tr).find(".txtDivisionName").html().toLowerCase();
    var NewDivision = $(".txtDivisionName").val().toLowerCase();
    alert(oldDivision)
    alert(NewDivision)

    if (oldDivision == NewDivision) {

      isDivisionExist = true;
      alert(" equal")

    } else {
      isDivisionExist = false;
      alert("not equal")
    }
  }


});
```

Comment: If you want to compare two objects then you can use following way :

if (oldDivision  === NewDivision ) {

Comment: add `.trim()` to botth your variables. `"x  " == "x"` will give `false`

Comment: *"are alerted the same"* - might look it, but they're not the same.  Try this `alert("[" + NewDivision + "]")` (and same for other)

Comment: also, if you want to compare text only than use `.text()`, not `.html()`.

Comment: Thankyou .trim() worked.Space  was the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply `.trim()` to remove extra spaces from text, if there

```
var oldDivision = $.trim($(tr).find(".txtDivisionName").html().toLowerCase());
var NewDivision = $.trim($(".txtDivisionName").val().toLowerCase());
```